# Why is Back on Fragment not working?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an XML for an activity and I have a android:id="@+id/fragment_container" FrameLayout that I use to add Fragments.

I currently have two fragments

[GameManager], [PlayerStatus]

Here is a snippet of the XML with the container

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >
```

I add fragment [GameManager] as follows from the main activity:

```
        //Start the fragment
        Fragment gameManager = new GameManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container,gameManager)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

From the GameManager Fragment class, I add a new fragment to the container as follows when a button is pressed:

```
public boolean buttonPress(Type button) {
    boolean canBuild = false;
    Player player = board.getCurrentPlayer();

    switch (button) {
      case INFO:
    //INFO IS THE BUTTON THAT IS ALWAYS VISIBLE IN TOP LEFT CORNER
    Log.d("myTag", "about to launch PLAYER INFO");

    PlayerStatus playerStatus = new PlayerStatus();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, playerStatus);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    break;
    .
    .
    .
```

In GameManager I setContentView as follows, where localgame.xml is the XML quoted above:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.localgame);
```

Everything works up to the point where I press the back button to return to the first fragment.

In the main activity I have the following code that checks the back button:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("myTag", "DETECTED BACK");
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.d("myTag", "THERE WAS SOMETHING IN THE FRAGSTACK");
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I press the back button, the back is properly detected and I can also see that there was something to pop() but the second fragment does not close. It simply remains visible. I want it so that when we press the back button from fragment [playerStatus] we return to the [GameManager] fragment.

Any hints are appreciated!

Edit: After making changes suggested by Martin, I get the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.settlers.hd, PID: 12710
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070025 (com.settlers.hd:id/fragment_container) for fragment GameManager{c2a128d #0 id=0x7f070025 GameManager}
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1527)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:485)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: you don't need to override `onBackPressed()` in activity class. When you press back button it will automatically pop the fragment backstack.

Comment: After popBackStack do not perform that transaction.

Comment: @arjun I also tried without overriding and it still seems to pop but does not close the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips.

1. `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();` is not  needed during your onBackPressed.
2. `PlayerStatus playerStatus = new PlayerStatus();` is no-bueno. Do what Google does (static method in the Fragment usually called `newInstance()` that returns `new PlayerStatusFragment();`
3. In your first transaction, you don't need to `replace` just `add`, for there's nothing to replace, also you probably don't want that first transaction in the backstack, unless you come from somewhere else, your first back in the first fragment should send you back via `super.onBackPressed();`.
4. Before adding a fragment like that, you have to check if it exists, perhaps the FragmentManager already has an instance of your fragment. To achieve that… use TAGs… like:

   `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, playerStatus, "SOME_TAG");`

Then you can do something like…

```
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("SOME_TAG");
if (f == null) {
     // The FragmentMananger doesn't have a stored instance… create a new one.
    f = YourFragment.newInstance();
}

fm.beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.container, f, "SOME_TAG")
  .addToBackStack(null)
  .commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes you suggested but now I get the following error:

E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f070025 (com.settlers.hd:id/fragment_container) for fragment GameManager{c2a128d #0 id=0x7f070025 GameManager}

Comment: Where do you get this? Like which line (post the relevant stack trace).

Comment: I added a trace to my original post

Comment: That means you're trying to tell Android to replace a fragment in a container that is not a child of the current view hierarchy. You may need to post more code. (XML, onCreateView/onViewCreated) for the fragment(s) and Activities. Are you sure your  your `R.id.fragment_container`, is a child of the layout specified in setContentView()? Also, Are these *nested* fragments (I suppose they are not, but asking just in case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136421/discussion-between-programmedchem-and-martin-marconcini).

Answer (score 0):

In buttonPress method, make change :

```
PlayerStatus playerStatus = new PlayerStatus();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, playerStatus,playerStatus.getClass().getSimpleName());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(playerStatus.getClass().getSimpleName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

You need to add third parameter in replace method and need to give tag in addToBackStack.

Comment: The TAG in the AddToBackStack is optional, for the FragmentManager doesn't need it to undo a transaction.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Comment: I think you should read what you linked: "String: An **optional** name for this back stack state, **or null**.". I can also tell you it's not needed because I have not set that back stack name in over 6 years of Android Development.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line when you transaction of GameManager Fragment

```
Fragment gameManager = new GameManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container,gameManager)
              //  .addToBackStack(null) remove this line
                .commit();
```

You have remove one more line in `onBackPressed()`

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("myTag", "DETECTED BACK");
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.d("myTag", "THERE WAS SOMETHING IN THE FRAGSTACK");
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
           // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit(); remove this line
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you say why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code in Parent Activity**

```
 @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment instanceof FragmentOne) {
           //here handle fragmentOne backpress
        }else if (fragment instanceof FragmentTwo) {
           //here handle fragmentTwo backpress
        }else {
          super.onBackPressed();              
        }
   }
```

Hope this will help!!!